# Setup Mailgun with Cloudflare subdomain

Tags: cloudflare, mailgun, email

I'm trying to setup my domain to receive emails through Mailgun and Cloudflare, and i think i'm really closest but can't make it work.

In Mailgun, i've all DNS verified:

[image]

I think the problem is in Cloudflare, configuring the subdomain (that Mailgun suggest me to create ***mg.mydomain.com***)

[image]

I have not got any record related with the subdomain (mg.mydomain.com). Is any change i'm something?

Also, I already setup a Route in mailgun to redirect incoming emails to my email address.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck in fixing this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: same issue here, everything is verified but I can't receive any emails

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer here:
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/setting-mx-records-for-a-subdomain/4942/2

What you need to do is:

**On Mailgun:**

1. Setup a domain for your incoming email (e.g.: `foo.example.com`)

**On Cloudflare:**

1. Go to DNS
2. Add an A record for your subdomain (`foo.example.com`)
3. Add an MX record. For the first field (name), put: `foo`.
4. When you click 'click to configure', it will open a dialog box where you can put the values for `mxa.mailgun.org`
5. Repeat for `mxb.mailgun.org`

Comment: An A record is not required. See https://www.chrisanthropic.com/blog/2014/mail-forwarding-with-mailgun-and-cloudflare/

Answer (score 2):

For the CNAME record, you just need to make sure that the status is configured as 'DNS Only' (the little cloud on the right is grey)

[image: Cloudflare DNS Configurations]

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. My problem was different from the OP. I was unable to track clicks in my email.